# Leave transition not being applied for ReactCSSTransitionGroup

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component:

```
  <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
    transitionName={transitionName}
    transitionAppear={true}
    transitionLeave={true}
  >
    {children}
  </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

And the following css classes:

```
.slide-appear {
  max-height: 0;
}

.slide-appear.slide-appear-active {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: visible;
  transition: max-height 500ms ease-in;
}

.slide-leave {
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.slide-leave.menu-leave-active {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0px;
  transition: max-height 500ms ease;
}
```

The transitions are working for appear but not for leave.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/v1-stable#disabling-animations), you disabled leave animation by using this prop:

```
transitionLeave={false}
```

Just remove it, problem solved.

Also as quick reminder, `transitionAppear` is used to [enable animation after initial mount](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/v1-stable#animate-initial-mounting) of the component, not to enable enter animation.